# How do I specify my whitespace style in Eclipse and reformat an offending document?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, tabs, format, whitespace

I have a document that is mixed HTML, JavaScript, and PHP. I edit it in Eclipse.

I am not the original author of the document, I am modifying it.

When modifying it, Eclipse's TAB and SHIFT+TAB (Indent and Unindent) do not function as expected.

Any indentation I insert by pressing TAB can be undone with SHIFT+TAB, but the indentation already in the document cannot be undone the same way. Pressing SHIFT+TAB in this case does nothing.

It seems the whitespacing in this file is different than what Eclipse expects.

My natural coding style (which came from customizing VIM) is spaces-only, with my TAB and SHIFT+TAB inserting and removing four spaces at a time.

How do I reprogram Eclipse for this, and then get Eclipse to restyle this document of unknown formatting to restore my keyboard shortcuts to normal behavior?

I understand that [Window] -> [Preferences] -> (language) -> [Code Style] contains a lot of options, but that's more than I was looking to do right now, plus I commonly find myself working in a lot of different Eclipse installations. Are there predefined Code Styles I can find somewhere for this particular style and import? I would imagine it is a relatively common style.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way no import a particular set of preferences, which seems what you are looking for. You import and export them as a whole (and it doesn't work very well, by the way).

I am afraid what you have to do is to configure them yourself in the preferences and edit the code more or less manually.